# Replica Lag In Multiple Servers

Tags: server-setup

I was reading an article about youtube in it's early years http://highscalability.com/youtube-architecture and came across the term Replica Lag. What exactly is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replica lag is the delay between updating a database on the main server and having it replicated to all other servers.

In a heavily loaded database system it can take some time for updates to be processed by all the other servers.